# UnFlatten Array using Underscore

Tags: underscore.js

I need to get the unflattened data into the correct format. 
Can some one help me get this working?
Here is a JSFiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/kawells/vse7fbn3/4/

```
  var arr = [{"id":"33155","comment":"Program 02 - Student Care - Library training","isfreetext":"0","snapshotfactorid":"1","ssprogramname":"Student Care","ssprogramnumber":"2","ssfactorname":"","ssfactornumber":"","isselected":false,"reportcommentid":"13738"},
{"id":"33154","comment":"Program 02 - Student Care - Library book acquired ","isfreetext":"0","snapshotfactorid":"1","ssprogramname":"Student Care","ssprogramnumber":"2","ssfactorname":"","ssfactornumber":"","isselected":false,"reportcommentid":"13737"},
{"id":"33656","comment":"Program 09 - Communications Check  Communications Check Student addressed","isfreetext":"0","snapshotfactorid":"2","ssprogramname":"Communication","ssprogramnumber":"9","ssfactorname":"","ssfactornumber":"","update_id":"1415294556708","isselected":false,"reportcommentid":"14234"},
{"id":"33658","comment":"Program 09  Communications Check - counselling conducted weekly for Student ","isfreetext":"0","snapshotfactorid":"2","ssprogramname":"Communication","ssprogramnumber":"9","ssfactorname":"","ssfactornumber":"","isselected":false,"reportcommentid":"14236"}]

grouped = _.map(_.groupBy(arr, 'ssprogramnumber'), function(b) {
    return _.extend(_.pick(b[0], 'ssprogramnumber', 'ssprogramname'), {
        factors: _.map(b, function(elem) {
            return _.pick(elem, 'snapshotfactorid', 'comment')
        })
    });
});

    document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + (JSON.stringify(grouped, null, " "))
```

It should look like:

```
[
 {
  "ssprogramnumber": "2",
  "ssprogramname": "Student Care",
  "factors": [
   {
    "snapshotfactorid": "1",
    comments:[{id:33155,"comment": "Program 02 - Student Care - Library training"},
               {id:33154,"comment": "Program 02 - Student Care - Library book acquired "}]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "ssprogramnumber": "9",
  "ssprogramname": "Communication",
  "factors": [
   {
    "snapshotfactorid": "2",
     comments:[{id: 33656 ,"comment": "Program 09 - Communications Check  Communications Check Student addressed"},
               {id:33658,"comment": "Program 09  Communications Check - counselling conducted weekly for Student "}]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

---ANSWER to second Question Found--
For those who may need to know see below.

var programgroups = _.groupBy(arr, 'ssprogramnumber');

var result = _.map(programgroups, function(program){

```
var snapshotgroups = _.groupBy(program, 'snapshotfactorid');

return {
    ssprogramnumber: program[0].ssprogramnumber,
    ssprogramname: program[0].ssprogramname,
    factors: _.map(snapshotgroups, function(snapshotfactor){

        return {

            snapshotfactorid: snapshotfactor[0].snapshotfactorid, 
            ssfactornumber: snapshotfactor[0].ssfactornumber,
             ssfactorname: snapshotfactor[0].ssfactorname,
            comments: _.map(snapshotfactor, function(comment){
                return _.pick(comment, 'id', 'comment');
            })
        }
    })
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var programgroups = _.groupBy(arr, 'ssprogramnumber');

var result = _.map(programgroups, function(program){

    var snapshotgroups = _.groupBy(program, 'snapshotfactorid');

    return {
        ssprogramnumber: program[0].ssprogramnumber,
        ssprogramname: program[0].ssprogramname,
        factors: _.map(snapshotgroups, function(snapshotgroup, snapshotfactorid){
            return {
                snapshotfactorid: snapshotfactorid,
                comments: _.map(snapshotgroup, function(comment){
                    return _.pick(comment, 'id', 'comment');
                })
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Gruff, can you tell me how to add  sfactornumber and ssfactorname to the factors level next to snapshotfactorid? It seems to be more difficult than I would have thought. Thanks

Comment: factors is an array of the data grouped by snapshotfactorid. Do you want the factors to be grouped by snapshotfactorid, sfactornumber  and ssfactorname?

Comment: I actually got lucky and figured it out. It seemed tricky though. Thanks I'll add it as an answer